# Energy of an inductor and capacitor

Tags: capacitor, inductor, energy

The energy of an inductor is \$\frac 12 LI^2\$ and a capacitor is \$\frac 12 CV^2\$. Why isn't the frequency also included in the formulas? As a higher frequency wave is more energetic than a low frequency wave.

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't the frequency also included in the formulas?

These formulas are for the instantaneous energy. The energy stored in the inductor or capacitor at an exact moment in time.

If an AC signal is applied, the stored energy will cycle at twice the signal frequency.

> As a higher frequency wave is more energetic than a low frequency wave.

A high frequency photon has more energy than a low frequency photon. But a classical wave is made up of many photons and it's certainly possible to have a low power wave at 100 GHz or a very high powered wave at a few millihertz or even deliver very high power at DC.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! Those formulas are basically a way to calculate the maximum charge of the inductor or capacitor, not a way to measure the actual energy stored in the device when subject to an AC source. In other words, if you put a sine wave (of whatever frequency) into a capacitor or inductor, the formula will only tell you the maximum amount of charge that component can have.

You can check out these videos I put together for more info:

1. The Three Effects of Inductors:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btv0uRi3xJ0
2. The Three Effects of Capacitance:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_P1rvhEeiI
3. AC Step Response and Identifying Parasitic Inductance:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heufatGyL1s

Answer (score -1):

If you are changing the current or voltage in time, then the energy levels also change but the storage energy averaged over a cycle does not get affected by frequency but the impedance coupling is affected by frequency.

Wave energies are from conductive emissions not reactive storage. We are talking about passive reactive storage elements here.